# Returning string[] from C# to Excel

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, vba

I have this method in C# (complied as dll):

```
    public string[] Person() 
    {
        string[] arrPerson = new string[3];
        arrPerson[0] = "Adam";
        arrPerson[1] = "Ceasar";
        arrPerson[2] = "David";

        return arrPerson;
    }
```

And I want to receive the list of persons in Excel (VBA code, which can reach other functions in the dll):

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim obj As New ClassTest2.Calc
    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = obj.Person

    Sheet.Range("A1:C1").Value = arr
End Sub
```

But the row "arr = objPerson" throws an error, index out of bounds.

How do I return a string[] to Excel?

Comment: function person must return 2D array [,] and also as far as I remember you need to register the dll if you want to add them to references.

Comment: Is this (the second part) VBA in excel? Are you using regasm and do /codebase for your C# assembly?

Comment: Do you have `Option Base 1` on top of your module?

Comment: For the record, `Person` is a bad name for that method. For a start, it is returning an array so it should be `People` and it is a method and not a property or field so it should be `GetPeople`. Method names should ALWAYS be verb-based.

Comment: The first code i C#, the second VBA. I edited the text to make it clearer.
As to Option Base 1, I do not have it, tested it, but same problem: index out of bounds.

Comment: The out of bounds error is propagated from the C# code. Base on the code you posted, it should not be occurring. Set your C# project up for debugging. Project Menu->Project Properties->Debug Tab->Start Action->Click Start External Program->set the path to Excel. You can also add the workbook path to the "Command line Arguments" box (enclose the path in quotes: "path to WB").  Set a breakpoint in your C# method and start debugging (F5). Excel should open and you can then run your VBA code. The C# breakpoint should be hit and bring VS to the foreground.